# can I deploy directly to Azure Virtual Machine from repository in Azure DevOps?

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine

I have an ASP.NET application project in Azure DevOps and I am trying to set up a build and release pipeline that will deploy the source code to an app in a virtual machine in Azure.

I tried to add the virtual machine in the Environments section of the Azure Devops project but did not succeed. I am not sure if it is the right approach.

can you please recommend the best-practice followed in such scenarion.

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to deploy your web app to app service instead of a VM? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the reason is that the app is hosted under the IIS of a virtual machine and I would like to benefit from AzureDevOps to manage the process as is the case in App Services.

Comment: @Kevin-Lu. This is actually the first time I am building a release pipeline and my first question on Stackover overflow :D.

Comment: You can usually deploy an asp.net web app directly to app service and it's often easier than fiddling with VM's and IIS

Comment: Hi @MohamdiVeten. Don't worry, if you have any questions related to the topic, I will help you. On the other hand, if the answer could give you some help, you can consider accepting it as answer. This will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the Build and Release Pipeline to deploy the Asp.Net Project, I suggest that you could use [Deployment Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) and IIS(Windows) or Nginx(ubuntu) on Azure VM.

**Note:** The Deployment Group can be used in Azure Devops Release Pipeline. The Environment can be used in Build Pipeline.

Here are the steps about use Deployment Group to deploy Asp.net app to IIS:

**Step1:** You need to config the IIS on Azure VM.

Here is a doc about the detailed steps:[Set up IIS on Windows Virtual Machine](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/set-up-iis-on-windows-virtual-machine/)

**Step2:** You could create the Deployment Group target on Azure VM.

Here are two methods to add Deployment Group target to Azure VM.

1. Log in to the VM remotely and deploy using the Powershell script about Deploying Deployment Group target in **Pipelines -> Deployment Groups -> Target Deployment Group -> Details**.
2. Use the **Azure resource group deployment task Version 2** (The latest is V3, but this option can be directly used in V2) to deploy Deployment Group.

[image]

**Step3:** You could use IIS web deploy task to deploy the Asp.net Project to Azure VM.

[image]

For more detailed steps about the Process, you could refer to this Blog: [Deploying to Azure VM using Deployment Groups](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/deploymentgroups/)

**Update:**

You need to check the zip file path in IIS web Deploy task.

[image]

You could click the "..." option to select the correct zip path.

Comment: I managed to register the VM in the Depolyment groups. Consequently, I did the following :
1- I set up a build piepline of my asp.net project. The build produces an artifact
2- I create a new release pipeline with one job with 2 tasks: IIS Web App Manage and IIS Web App Depoy.
3- when  I select the release pipeline and click deploy the deloyment fails with the error : Error: No package found with specified pattern.

Comment: Hi @MohamdiVeten. For this issue, you need to set the correct path in IIS web deploy task. The zip file path could have issue.  Please check my update.